# SimpleMDE preview in html page without markdown éditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, markdown, simplemde

I have a problem with SimpleMDE, I would like to have the "preview" in another . With bold, italics ... to then be able to reuse it on a web page without needing the editor. Ideally, you would need a Markdown "translator" to css. I don't know if it's clear what I'm saying but in any case thank you for